# NextJS and React Cannot read properties of undefined and element.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am using NextJS and`getServerSideProps` to get some data from the db with Prisma. In the development envirnoment, I had no issue. But when deployed with vercel, I am constantly running into issues.

Here is what I've done:

1. I created the API route that get the Toto lists from the db. In this function I simply return the shopping list array as following:

```
import prisma from '../../../lib/prisma'



export default async function handler(req, res) {

    const { userId } = req.query;
    if (req.method === 'GET') {
      try {
        const shoppingLists = await prisma.List.findMany({ where: { userId: userId[0] }});
        res.status(200).send(shoppingLists);
      } 
      catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Something went wrong. Please try again'});  
      }
    }
    else {
      res.status(500).json({message: 'Invalid method requested!'});
    }
}
```

2. After this, I created a separate folder called abstraction layer where I do all the DB interactions. I am using axios. In this function I fetch the data and return it as list.data;

```
// Get all lists
export const getAllLists = async userId => {
    try {
        const lists = await axios.get(`https://next-shopping-list.vercel.app/api/get-all-lists/${userId}`, { 
            headers: { "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate,compress" } // This is taken from internet because I had other errors "invalid file"
        });
        return lists.data;    
    } 
    catch (error) {
        console.log('Abstraction layer error: ', error);
        return 'Something went wrong. Please try again later';
    }
}
```

// The component (Dashboard) that will contain get server side props and the return()
3. Here it comes the problem. I use SSR because I want to also protect this page. In this  function I use the function `getAllLists` from the "abstraction layer" and return the shopping lists with the 'lists' prop...

```
export const getServerSideProps = async context => {

  // get sessions with added user Id in the session object
  const session = await requireAuthentication(context);

  // Get all lists
  const shoppingLists = await getAllLists(session?.user.userId);
console.log(shoppingLists);

  if (!session) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/signup',
        permanent: false
      }
    }
  }
  
  else {
    return {
      props: {
        newSession: session,
        lists:       shoppingLists
      }
    }
  }
}
```

4. After creating the component, I start to get errors trying to map over the array of lists, throwing two errors:

- The 'props.lists.map()...' is not a function.
- Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

```
const Lists = props => {

    const router = useRouter();
    console.log(props.lists);


    const handleDeleteList = async listId => {
        const status = await deleteList(listId);
        console.log(status);      
        if (status.status === 201) {
            router.replace(router.asPath);
        }
    }

    const handleCheckList = async listId => router.push(`/list-items/${listId}`);
 

    // New try re
  return (
    <article>
        {props.lists.length > 0 && props.lists.map(list => (
            <div key={list.id}>
                <div className='flex justify-between my-2 cursor-pointer p-2 items-center'>
                    <p>{ list.title }</p>
                    <div className='flex gap-3'>
                        <AiOutlineDelete size={30} onClick={() => handleDeleteList(list.id)}/>
                        <AiOutlineEye size={30} onClick={() => handleCheckList(list.id)} /> 
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        ))}
    </article>
  )
}

export default Lists
```

I don't understand what have I done wrong... In development envirnoment it worked perfectly....

```
{/* List is empty and display empty message // Else show list */}
        {props.lists && <Lists lists={props.lists}/>}
        {props.lists.length === 0 && 
        <p className="mt-2 text-2xl font-extralight">No lists created yet.</p>}
      </aside>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component is expecting `props.lists` to be an array, looks like initially `props.list` doesn't have an array. That's why it is causing errors as `props.lists.length`, and the `props.lists.map` is only available if `props.lists` is an array.

So before calling it, make sure `props.list` is an array, you can use optional chaining (`props?.lists.?length`)

Comment: it worked. Thank you. What should I do to get this errors in development also? Is fustrating when in development everything went well but in production nothing works...

Comment: Yeah , these are the flaws of JS, and that's why I like TS more, it takes extra time to define types, but at least does not cause such errors during run time or on production. Optional chaining is a must thing to implement if you are applying such array methods on the keys of an object. It could break